# How to run QB64 on Backend

Tags: backend, qb64

Is it somewhat possible to use QB64 as a server side scripting language?

I don't want it to be as good as PHP, etc., but it should have:

- File I/O
- Cookies/Sessions
- Input from HTML Form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is somewhat possible!

The GeekBasic web server has made this possible. Get the TCP/IP Web Server from [Github](https://github.com/geekbasic/GeekBasicWebServer).

Features:

- fast file serving
- scripts are similar to PHP and ASP
- scripts may utilize cookies, forms, subs, if/then blocks, strings, arrays, and more.
- scripts may include sub files
- scrips may access files within the www directory and sub-directories for i/o
- able to neatly log high volumes of requests
- install package includes an IDE